# Setting ALL colors on WPF ComboBox using styles?

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I asked this question a few days ago and got some answers, non of which really helped me with the problem, so I am trying a fresh approach.

I want to be able to set the colors (foreground, background, and border) of the textbox used by a comboBox so that it can have a number of different values, based on a trigger.  With a textbox, this is easy, just use setters on those properties and you are done.

So given that I have a trigger as follows:

```
<Trigger Property="someProperty"  Value="true"> 
    <!-- Insert Setters Here -->
<Setter Property="Foreground"
    Value="Red" />
</Trigger>
```

What Setters would I insert into the above to change the 3 aforementioned colors of the textbox used by the combobox? For each trigger, assume that every color will change.  It appears that Foreground works except for disabled.

I am under the impression that changing the colors based on an "IsEnabled" trigger (when false) can be tricky, but not sure why. But I need to support that and a number of other triggers based on custom attached properties or validations.

For the background, I have tried a whole bunch of options including ComboBox.Background, TextElement.Background, Panel.Background, etc., but all I get is a plain white background.

One other thing occurred to me is that if those should work, there may be some resource library in the calling tree that may be setting the background color in a way that won't allow me to change it, but, if so, how would I be able to find out?

Thank you!

Comment: When a combo box is in the non-editable state, the thing that *looks* like a text block is actually a toggle button.  Are you referring to the text box that appears when the combo box is in the editable state?  Or both?

Answer (score 1):

As I told you in your last (now duplicated) question, you will need to define a new `ControlTemplate` to achieve your goal.

For future reference:

> Asking duplicate questions on StackOverflow is *not* approved by the community, *especially if you are asking a duplicate of your own question*. If you do not understand your answer(s) or do not feel that they answer your question adequately, you should ask the answer author(s) to explain it further in *that* question.

Now I'll get off my soap box and get you further on your way to achieving your goal. As I said, you will need to define a new `ControlTemplate`... there is no way around this. The reason for this is simple - you want to add `Trigger`s to affect the XAML controls that are defined *inside* the default `ControlTemplate`, but you have no other way to do this from XAML.

So, how do we define a new `ControlTemplate`? It's quite simple really: we just define some XAML in the `Template` property that describes the way that we want the control to look and behave. Please refer to the link that I provided you with for help with this in your last post. Additionally, here is a *very* simplified example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" Padding="2">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Apply this `Style` to a `ComboBox` with the `IsEnabled` property set to `False` and you will see that it is red. Now you're probably thinking 'that doesn't look like a `ComboBox`' and you'd be right. That's because I just replaced all of the XAML from the default `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate` with a little bit that slightly resembles just the drop down section for simplicity.

Your job now is to define your own `ControlTemplate` that replicates the default XAML and adds the relevant `Trigger`s that I have shown you in this and your last post. In the example, notice how the `Trigger.TargetName` is set to `Border`, which is the name of the internal `Border` control used. You will need to do this for each element that you want to colour.

Here is a link to the default `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox` control. When you see how large it is, you will understand why I didn't use it in the example.

[ComboBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the right answer.  But oh my, the tone is a dramatic departure from your normal chirpy and cheerful one.  Suggest an edit...

Comment: @GaryVass, thank you for your comment. I accept your point and made a few changes just now... however, it's funny because I already 'cleaned it up' quite considerably before I posted it. :) I feel that it is now all reasonable. I also believe that the note on duplication is valid, as I have noticed how quickly some StackOverflow users like to close duplicate questions.

Comment: Sheridan, I made it clear that I had posted the question before (unlike some who will keep asking without such a declaration) and explained why.  For someone new to xaml, editing a template to add support for colors is daunting and I was hoping that someone had already figured it out and could post that code.  In any case, I contacted someone (outside of SO) and they were able to help me solve this.  And given that you had seen the other answer, I kinda thought that you would have realized that I was asking for something else in the first place.